# Can I remove this script from my page without consequences?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am told by Google Page Test speed to remove the script below from my HTML `<head>` tag because it blocks the rendering of the page. From my research this script load a library or something like this. Is it wise to remove it? Can I do this without consequences on running other JavaScript on my page?

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: It's likely that quite a bit of the rest of your page's code relies on that library.

Comment: Hi welcome, you should post an example of your webpage

Comment: Depends, do you use jQuery?

Comment: Remove it and test the page to find out.

Comment: `From my research this script load a library or something like this.` What kind of research did you do to not understand / know what's jQuery? `:)`

Comment: I believe the test page is telling you to put the script tag in the bottom, but still within, the HTML Tags. The reason for this is the browser will load that file before continuing on with the rest of the page, thus briefly blocking any content that occurs after that link. Inserting the script tags at the bottom yield better perceived performance.

Comment: sounds more like you have errors being thrown from something other code

Comment: @charlietfl Did you read the question? LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar i sure did, and find it highly unlikely that loading the library itself blocks anything

Comment: @charlietfl Google should be crazy, coz the script is loaded from Google CDN and it says it is bad. LoL.

Comment: I'm A physicist (pretty good) not a programmer. I now some PHP but that's all. Until this evening I did not know what is JQuerry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the test page is telling you to put the `script tag` in the bottom, but still within, the `html/body tags`. The reason for this is the browser will load that file before continuing on with the rest of the page, thus briefly blocking any content yet to be loaded. You're also using a `CDN` so if there is a bad network connection then you can expect for there to be perceived performance issues. Inserting the script tags at the bottom yields better perceived performance.

As to whether or not you need jQuery, depends on if your are utilizing it or not, as @Dave Newton said.

Refer to these:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CDN

Comment: Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
Your page has 2 blocking script resources and 7 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
Remove render-blocking JavaScript:
    https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: I forgit to say, this is a blogger blog and you can visualize the content of any pages here https://students-homework.blogspot.com  @Michael

Comment: Aha, i understand now, I'll move the script from the head, to the end of the body.

Comment: Yes I accept it as the right answer. I do not know what button to push to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. In fact I added the async='async' and now everything is good.

Comment: @user36636 you have much to learn friend, just keep doing it!